# App getting crash immediately after launch in android - React-native

Tags: android, react-native

I updated RN version 0.64 to 0.67, after adding that app getting crash immediately after launch without any error, please help me to fix issue

i ran adb logcat --buffer=crash

> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.tapp, PID: 8869
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed
> resolution of: Landroidx/core/view/OnReceiveContentViewBehavior;
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1530)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1614)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:999)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:661)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2173)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2671)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.originalInstallDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2753)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2735)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2120)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.setEnterActivityOptions(ActivityTransitionState.java:171)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8123)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3493)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2142)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.view.OnReceiveContentViewBehavior" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~TvRq8yhbRZPMs3xyzJ7jGA==/com.tapp-xotKQaDfq4sZ-tA54NPe6w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~TvRq8yhbRZPMs3xyzJ7jGA==/com.tapp-xotKQaDfq4sZ-tA54NPe6w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~TvRq8yhbRZPMs3xyzJ7jGA==/com.tapp-xotKQaDfq4sZ-tA54NPe6w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> 08-02 00:48:57.646 8869 8869 E AndroidRuntime: ... 29 more

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);


def nativeArchitectures = 
project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

// compileOptions {
//     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
// }

defaultConfig {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.3.1' }
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' 
}
    }
    applicationId "com.tapp"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "19.0"
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal 
 APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
    if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
    }
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        if (nativeArchitectures) {
            ndk {
                abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
            }
        }
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
        }

    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines- 
core:1.3.3"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3"

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
implementation project(path: ':library')

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
 
 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

 debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:
 flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}"  
 ) 
{
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
 }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network- 
  plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.implementation
into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli- 
 platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); 
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector- 
icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I can give is go through this migration helper link and make sure all files have been adjusted accordingly.

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.0&to=0.67.0

Comment: Hi @obsidianlab, i followed same link to upgrade the RN version

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in andoidx.appcompat class not found

In app build.gradle, I changed this line of dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

or chack the version of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
```

I have below code in my build.gradle (Project)

```
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
```

but I am using react native 0.68.2 at the moment.

Comment: Hi @Iva i added that dependency but getting same error, can you please look at my build.gradle file and please let me know if any mistakes in that file

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was able to fix my crash issue by adding these line to build.gradle file

**app/build.gradle**

```
 defaultConfig {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0' }
    }
  {...}
}

{....}

dependencies {

implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
version {
    strictly '1.3.1'
 }
}
```

thanks